# Android Crosswalk Project: How to use css?

Tags: android, css, crosswalk, crosswalk-project

I created a new project for testing `Crosswalk Project`.
I'm trying to load some content with css file but the css doesn't work at all.
Code from MainActivityFragment:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import org.xwalk.core.XWalkPreferences;
import org.xwalk.core.XWalkSettings;
import org.xwalk.core.XWalkView;

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {

    private XWalkView xWalkWebView;

    private View mContentView;

    private static final String page = "<html>\n" +
            "            <head>\n" +
            "\n" +
            "                <link href=\"primary.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\"/>\n" +
            "\n" +
            "                <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\"/>\n" +
            "\n" +
            "            </head>\n" +
            "\n" +
            "            <body>\n" +
            "\n" +
            "                <ol>\n" +
            "<li>Harum aut nostrum</li>\n" +
            "</ol>\n" +
            "<ol>\n" +
            "<li>Saepe aut non numquam</li>\n" +
            "<li>Sed aliquid</li>\n" +
            "<li>Quo rerum quia veniam dolore</li>\n" +
            "<li>Doloribus dolores</li>\n" +
            "<li>Excepturi adipisci ad enim consequatur</li>\n" +
            "<li>Enim qui autem iure aut deserunt</li>\n" +
            "<li>Minima natus ratione rerum officia</li>\n" +
            "<li>Non sed et eveniet aut</li>\n" +
            "</ol>\n" +
            "<p><iframe width=\"840\" height=\"473\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/10r9ozshGVE?feature=oembed\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe></p>\n" +
            "<p>Facere <a title=\"Qui.\" href=\"https://rohan.net/magnam-rerum-repudiandae-est-cupiditate-ea.html\">id</a> nemo. Quasi dolorem est et. Modi aperiam est magni. Necessitatibus non labore ut qui atque Aliquam modi dolores nulla odit. Placeat vel vel quia nisi distinctio. Dolores <a title=\"Reprehenderit dolor blanditiis.\" href=\"http://batz.org/maxime-totam-sed-voluptatum-explicabo-voluptas-distinctio\">porro autem rerum</a> ex. Consequuntur quia quia Quod voluptas dolorem accusamus nemo. Tempora nostrum iste qui vel Non esse aut aut ut ducimus. sit est sed ad. <a title=\"Eos minus.\" href=\"http://dooley.net/possimus-impedit-enim-ex-numquam-qui-esse\">unde quibusdam in tempore et</a> eum recusandae. Molestiae omnis harum consequatur officia. adipisci iure libero voluptatem necessitatibus est.</p>\n" +
            "<p><img src=\"https://reviworx.com/~reviworx/dev/wp_frm/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/f46d91f8-8923-3a0a-a6f8-7413399aa33e.jpg\" alt=\"Totam voluptatem\" /></p>\n" +
            "<h6>Minus corrupti explicabo amet aut suscipit. Porro rerum corrupti a</h6>\n" +
            "<p><img class=\"alignright\" src=\"https://reviworx.com/~reviworx/dev/wp_frm/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/e3b46cb3-6f7c-383e-abc0-194e31ad37ee.jpg\" alt=\"Labore a adipisci in modi sunt\" /></p>\n" +
            "\n" +
            "\n" +
            "            </body>\n" +
            "        </html>";

    public MainActivityFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        mContentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        xWalkWebView = (XWalkView) mContentView.findViewById(R.id.xwalkWebView);

        xWalkWebView.setInitialScale(1);

        XWalkSettings settings = xWalkWebView.getSettings();

        if(settings != null) {

//            settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

//            settings.setSupportZoom(true);

            settings.setDefaultFontSize(20);

//            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
//
//                settings.setDisplayZoomControls(false);
//
//            }

        }

//        xWalkWebView.load("https://crosswalk-project.org", null);

        xWalkWebView.load(null, page);

        // turn on debugging
        XWalkPreferences.setValue(XWalkPreferences.REMOTE_DEBUGGING, true);

        return mContentView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (xWalkWebView != null) {
            xWalkWebView.pauseTimers();
            xWalkWebView.onHide();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (xWalkWebView != null) {
            xWalkWebView.resumeTimers();
            xWalkWebView.onShow();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (xWalkWebView != null) {
            xWalkWebView.onDestroy();
        }
    }

}
```

And here is my css file:

```
@font-face { 
    font-family: 'thesansarabic'; 
    /* src: url('DejaVuSans.ttf'); This doesn't work */
    /* src: url('fonts/DejaVuSans.ttf'); Neither is this */
    src: url('file:///android_asset/fonts/thesansarabic-plain.otf'); /* but this does */
}

body {
    font-size: small;
    font-family: 'thesansarabic';

    display: -webkit-box;
    display: flex;

    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    flex-direction: column;

    padding-top: 48px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 48px;
    padding-left: 10px;

    box-sizing: border-box;

    /*direction: ltr;*/
}

img {

    max-width: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;

}

/*iframe, video {

    max-width: 100%;

}*/

/* Portrait */
@media screen
  and (orientation: portrait) {

    iframe, video {

        max-width: 100%;
        max-height 40%;
        height: 250px;

    }

}

/* Landscape */
@media screen
  and (orientation: landscape) {

    iframe, video {

        max-width: 60%;
        max-height 30%;
        height: 200px;

    }

}
```

**Note: This code works on default android webview.**
Here is how i'm Embedding the Crosswalk Project:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://download.01.org/crosswalk/releases/crosswalk/android/maven2'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
    compile 'org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library:17.46.448.10'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

our developers have resolved your problem, you can just add `file:///android_asset/` like `XWalkView.load("file:///android_asset/", content);` to make css work and No need to add any full-path in your css file. `src: url('fonts/DejaVuSans.ttf');` also will work. About your second question of crosswalk samples on android, You can find most android embedding apis' usecases on [embeddingapi](https://github.com/crosswalk-project/crosswalk-test-suite/tree/master/usecase/usecase-embedding-android-tests/embeddingapi) or [embeddingapi-async](https://github.com/crosswalk-project/crosswalk-test-suite/tree/master/usecase/usecase-embedding-android-tests/embeddingapi-async). They are two ways of using crosswalk(sync & async).

Answer (score 0):

I'm from Crosswalk team. I have reproduced your code locally and it's temporarily a bug as we know, you can track it in this [XWALK-6541](https://crosswalk-project.org/jira/browse/XWALK-6541). I can provide you a second way to use css if you want. You can just use `XWalkView.load("file:///android_asset/page.html", null)`, it works fine. Let me know if you have any other questions. Thanks.

Comment: Hello Jacky, Thank you for helping me. Can you provide some samples for using Crosswalk Project for Android?
And please change your answer so i can accept it.

Comment: Also i have this bug when rotate screen while `XWalkView` playing video on full screen mode. Logcat `A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000008 (code=1), thread 3909 (s.crosswalkdemo)`

Comment: About this bug I suggest you propose another question, so we can help you. Thanks.